# How to refer to a text in an Ms Access table?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I want to refer to a data cell, which if it is equals to some string, it will do something.
The codes:

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Status") = "Reserved" Then
MessageBox.Show("Can't reserve")
End If
```

Is this the correct way to do this?
Because I failed doing so..

Comment: Why you are failing? Do you have an exception? Witch one? Or maybe the code is not showing the MessageBox when it should?

Comment: The program was not showing the message box

Comment: This is not a question about MS-ACCESS in any form whatsoever. The tag should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return type of:

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Status")
```

Also,

- Is the case different (uppercase in db ??)
- Check for leading/trailing spaces.
- Is the field in database fixed-length

#### U might want to try trim-ing the string before comparing:

For Ex, in VB6 i might hav tried:

```
IF lower(trim$(<thedbqueryhere>))= "reserved" then

    msgBox("Can't reserve")

End if
```

GoodLUCK!!

CVS @ 2600Hertz

Comment: do you have some reference to do it in VB.Net? i couldn't find any clear reference.

Comment: Plz try out magnifico's snippet above. That might *just* do the trick!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be checking the Value property of the cell.

Also here is the VB6 code by CVS @ 2600Hertz translated to VB.NET

```
Dim cell = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Status")
If cell.Value.ToUpperInvariant().Trim() = "Reserved".ToUpperInvariant() Then
    MessageBox.Show("Can't Reserve")
End If
```